# c# overriding virtual methods in MEF class doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, managed-extensions

I have an abstract base class and I'm inheriting from it in an extension assembly. And here is my code

`region Contract Assembly`

```
public interface IDummy
{
    int ForAbstractMethod();
    int ForVirtualMethod();
}

public abstract class BaseClass : IDummy
{
    public abstract int ForAbstractMethod();

    public virtual int ForVirtualMethod()
    {
        //Some base functionality
        return 0;
    }
}
#endregion

#region Extension Assembly

public class SomeExtension : BaseClass
{
    public override int ForAbstractMethod()
    {
        //I implement this method here, which is defined abstract in base class and this one works fine.
        return 100;
    }

    public override int ForVirtualMethod()
    {
        //Even though I override the virtual one here, still the one in the base class executes.
        return 1;
    }
}

#endregion


#region Main Program Assembly which references Contract Assembly

public class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        //... compose catalog and other stuff

        IDummy dummy = someFactory.GetInstanceFromCatalog<IDummy>();//I get an instance
        int a = dummy.ForAbstractMethod();//this works as expected and returns 100
        a = dummy.ForVirtualMethod();//here I expect it to return 1 since I overrode it in child class, but it returns still 0.

        //...other stuff
    }
}
```

Are there any differences between overriding virtual and abstact methods that I am not aware of or this is a specific case for MEF?
Thanks for any help...

Comment: I encountered the same problem.
Have you come to a decision?

Answer (score 3):

You're not declaring `ForVirtualMethod` as virtual on `BaseClass`. Change it to this

```
public virtual int ForVirtualMethod()
{
    //Some base functionality
    return 0;
}
```

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more details about virtual members declaration

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer or event declaration, and allow it to be overridden in a derived class.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I forgot to add virtual keyword. It is actually virtual in my real code. I just tried to clarify things by writing some dummy code and forgot to add virtual.

Comment: @dopache: that's weird. What does `GetInstanceFromCatalog` do?

Comment: That's just a piece of code for readers to mention that dummy instance didn't came out of nowhere.